# How can i extract some data from website and email it

Tags: java, php, parsing

As an example suppose i want my program to

1. Vist stackoverflow everyday
2. Find the most question in some tag for that day
3. Format it and then send it to my email address

I don't know how to do it , i know php more , but i have some understnading of Java , j2ee , spring MVC but not java network programming

Any guidelines how should i go

Comment: Sound to me you are looking for an RSS feed.

Comment: I don't know how you're gonna sort the whole day's data, but you can get rss feed by tag on here: http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/php

Comment: Actually SO is only example , but i may need ofr some other sites as well which don't have API , so i need to get proper method

Comment: then you will need to search for what is called as html scraping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're wanting to retrieve data from a website (i.e. over HTTP), you probably want to look into using one of many HTTP clients already written in Java or PHP.

[Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) is a good Java client used by many people. If you're invoking a RESTful interface, [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) has a nice client library.

On the PHP side of things, someone already mentioned file_get_contents... but you could also look into the [cURL library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

As far as emailing goes, there's a JavaMail API (I'll admit I'm not familiar with it), or depending on your email server you might jump through other hoops (for example Exchange can send email through their SOAP interfaces.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by looking at the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage).

Answer (score 1):

What you can possibly do is extract the contents of url and write it to a string buffer and then using JSOUP.jar (used to parse html elements) parse the html string to get the content of your choice.I have a small sample which does exactly that i read all the contents of the url into a string and then parse the content based on the CLASS TAG (here in this case it is question-hyperlink)

```
package com.tps.examples;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class URLGetcontent {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/questions");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Get the response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();

            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                // System.out.println(line);
                str.append(line);
            }

            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str.toString());
            Elements content = doc.getElementsByClass("question-hyperlink");

            for (int i = 0; i < content.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Question: " + (i + 1) + ".  " + content.eq(i).text());
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.println("*********************************");

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Once the data is extracted you can use `javamail` class to send the content in email.

Answer (score 0):

with `file_get_contents()` in PHP you cal also fetch files via HTTP:

```
$stackoverflow = file_get_contents("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Then you have to parse this. For many sites there are special APIs which you can request via JSON or XML.

If you know shell scripting (that's the way i do it for many sites - works great with a cronjob :)) then you can use `sed`, `wget`, `w3m`, `grep`, `mail` to do it...

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow and other stackexchange sites provide a simple API (stackapps). You Please check out.